# In the category of uniform spaces, is the completion of a quotient map also a quotient map?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, uniform-spaces

I asked this question about 2 months ago on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189332/in-the-category-of-uniform-spaces-is-the-completion-of-a-quotient-map-also-a-qu), but so far I received neither comments nor answers.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Hausdorff uniform spaces. A surjective uniformly continuous map $f: X \to Y$ is a *quotient map* if for every map $g$ from $Y$ to a uniform space $Z$ such that $g \circ f$ is uniformly continuous, $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ denote the completions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and let
$\hat f : \hat X \to \hat Y$ be the unique uniformly continuous extension of $f$.
Is $\hat f$ a quotient map?

If the answer is positive, a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: One problem with this definition of a quotient map that I have is that not every quotient map is surjective: if $Y$ is given the discrete uniformity, then function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is automatically a quotient map since every map $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is automatically continuous.

Comment: @joseph-van-name Thank you very much for this remark. I am indeed interested in surjective maps only and I have modified the definition accordingly.

Comment: The mapping $\widehat{f}$ may not map $\widehat{X}$ onto $\widehat{Y}$. For example, take any complete space with a quotient that is not complete. So perhaps OP wanted to ask if the mapping $\widehat{f}$ taken as a mapping $\widehat{X}\to\widehat{f}(\widehat{X})$ is a quotient.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to the question is yes, but there is a little gap (called "Gap-Statement" below) that needs to be filled - and of course there is still the possibility that the "Gap-Statement" is false.

Let's split the answer in two steps.

**Step 1.** Let $f:X\to Y$ be uniformly continuous, let  $\hat f: \hat X \to \hat Y$ be the uniformly continuous extension, and take a uniform space $Z$ and a *non*-continuous map $g:\hat Y \to Z$. Then we show that $g\circ \hat f: \hat X \to Z$ is not continuous.

I'm not entirely sure the following statement is correct - but if it is, it answers the question positively:

*"Gap-Statement"*. Let $X$ is a Hausdorff uniform space and let $i:X\to \hat X$ be the canonical map from $X$ to its extension. Let $Z$ be a uniform space and $g:\hat X \to Z$ be a map. Then $g$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $g\circ i: X\to Z$ is uniformly continuous.

(One direction is trivial.)

So let $f:X\to Y$ be uniformly continuous, let  $\hat f: \hat X \to \hat Y$ be the uniformly continuous extension, and take a uniform space $Z$ and a *non*-continuous map $g:\hat Y \to Z$. Let $i_X:X\to \hat X$ and $i_Y:Y\to \hat Y$ be the canonical maps from $X,Y$ to their extension. Using the "Gap-Statement" we get that $g\circ i_Y: Y\to Z$ is non-continuous. Since $f:X\to Y$ is a quotient map, the map $g\circ i_Y \circ f: X\to Z$ is non-continuous. Note that 
$$g\circ i_Y \circ f= g\circ \hat f \circ i_X.$$

So if $g\circ \hat f$ were continuous, then so would be $g\circ \hat f \circ i_X = g\circ i_Y \circ f$. But we just proved that this map is not continuous, so $g\circ \hat f: \hat X \to Z$ is not continuous, as desired.

**Step 2.** We have to show that if $f:X\to Y$ is surjective, then so is the continuous extension $\hat f: \hat X \to \hat Y$.

The proof for this is as follows. Note that the elements of $\hat Y$ are minimal Cauchy filters on $Y$, so let ${\cal G} \in \hat Y$ be a minimal Cauchy filter on $Y$. Then $$\{f^{-1}(V): V\in {\cal G}\}$$ is a filter base for a Cauchy filter on $X$ which contains a minimal Cauchy filter ${\cal F}$. It is not hard to show that $\hat f({\cal F}) = {\cal G}$, so $\hat f$ is surjective.

Comment: Step 2 rang an alert bell in my head and I found the following example in Bourbaki. Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual Euclidian metric and let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the uniform structure inherited from the compact space $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Then the identity map $X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous and surjective, but its continuous extension from $\hat X$ to $\hat Y$ is not surjective.

Comment: Oh I see.. Should I better delete my answer?